# Exibir texto original, com quebras de linhas, dentro da tag <a>

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando colocar um texto com mais de um paragrafo como link, mas a exibição dentro da *tag* `<a>` remove as quebras de linhas que há no texto. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="wpquery_link_filter(' <?= preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $value) ?> ', <?= $property['id'] ?>)">
    <?= $value ?>
</a>
```

Estou obtendo algo assim:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sem magna, eleifend id hendrerit vel, imperdiet sit amet ligula. Cras eleifend quam vel ex fringilla fringilla. Phasellus at nibh eget lorem ullamcorper faucibus tristique eu purus. Donec quis turpis porta, posuere mauris quis, elementum urna. Nunc maximus neque feugiat, pretium eros egestas, varius justo. Proin accumsan fringilla sapien ut varius. Cras non finibus nisi, eu pretium lacus. Pellentesque elementum maximus erat ut posuere. Vivamus elementum mauris et nisl ullamcorper, quis suscipit ipsum tempor. Proin sit amet dolor quam. Cras mattis malesuada dui. Morbi ac massa a odio facilisis vehicula. Sed a diam sed nisl egestas fermentum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum varius nec nibh at hendrerit. Quisque augue urna, lobortis ut cursus sed, bibendum sed orci. Donec maximus, erat ut elementum porttitor, erat elit fringilla enim, at imperdiet odio urna nec lorem. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut vitae sem dignissim, consequat metus non, vehicula augue. Donec quis nisl sit amet erat auctor tempus. Proin at sollicitudin turpis, sit amet vestibulum leo. Nunc tellus erat, consectetur a posuere non, aliquet id sem.*

Como posso fazer que a exibição permaneça como o texto original?

Answer (score 2):

O problema ocorre que as quebras de linha no texto não são renderizadas como quebra de linha no html, para isso existe a tag `<br>`. O que você precisa fazer é converter as quebras de linha da variável `$value` para a tag `<br>`.

Como o texto vem de uma variável PHP, exite a função nativa `nl2br` que faz exatamente isso. [Você confere a documentação desta função aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php), e o seu código com a função logo abaixo:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="wpquery_link_filter(' <?= preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $value) ?> ', <?= $property['id'] ?>)">
    <?= nl2br($value) ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Valeu pela dica, depois de pesquisar mais eu encontrei uma forma de fazer utilizando uma propriedade CSS. Propriedade `white-space: pre-wrap`, mas a sua solução também funcionaria.

Comment: na verdade, ele pode usar a tag <pre> com o link dentro